# Copy or backup and restore a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I want to make a copy of a database to run intensive analysis on while the original is in use. From what I [read](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/871f8057-d047-4370-8ddd-5e2c414c0edf/backup-while-database-is-in-use?forum=sqlkjmanageability), the database will not be locked during backup. I cannot find any information whether or not the database will be locked during copy using the [copy-wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-2017).

What is the most effective (fastest and using the least disk space) way to make a duplicate of a production-database on the same server?

Comment: You're already taking backups right? Restore last night's backup to a new database name and run your checks on that, it's going to be the simplest approach.

Comment: Back up and restore. Everytime. To copy the data file, you would have to detact the database from the server, a problem unto itself. If you're worried about the size of the backup, backup to a different device and shared storage (use the UNC path) and/or use compression (surely you're using 2012+ so, this isn't an enterprise only feature).

Comment: Backup/restore will be the fastest and easiest, and you can leverage existing backups for this need as @RichBenner suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways:

- [transaction log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/configure-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017): secondary database is read only for your OLAP queries
- [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017): secondary database can be modified

You may test a database snapshot, too but this method isolates the data state only not the workload.